# Need of $1$ in this proof?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

What is the need of a $1$ inside the $\mathbb{max}$ in this proof?
[image]

Comment: It is really important to ask these questions by the way. Over time, these details will make more and more sense.

Comment: @ElliotG, Thanks for encouragement. I was really concerned that asking these minute details would evoke criticism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's actually needed.  The only thing I could of is to ensure that no division by zero takes place, but the condition $-m'<a(n)<M'$ means that not both $m'$ and $M'$ can be zero, so it's actually unnecessary.

Comment: I agree with this answer. I think it's just a stylistic approach so that $a(n)$ and $b(n)$ are within $\frac\varepsilon2$ of their limits (without relying on the bounds of the sequence).

Answer (score 1):

The $1$ is there so that we have $$\frac{\varepsilon}{2M}\leq\frac\varepsilon2.$$ This way, we have each sequence being with $\frac\varepsilon2$ of its limit.

Comment: When did we use that? We just used that $\mathbb{L}_2\leq \mathbb{M}$??

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal: The proof doesn't explicitly use it. I think it is so that you have $|a(n)-L_1|<\frac\varepsilon2$ and $|b(n)-L_2|<\frac\varepsilon2$.

Answer (score 1):

It ensures that $M$ is not zero, which is problematic as you divide by $M$.

**Edit:** However, by strictness in  $m' \lt a(n) \lt M'$ we have $m' \neq M'$ and else $M$ could not be zero even without a $1$ there. I *guess* the $1$ makes it clearer that we do not divide by zero?

Comment: Because of the strict inequalities, I don't think $M$ could be $0$ (in particular, $-m'<M'$, so both can't be $0$).

Comment: +1 for raising the idea of division by $0$.

Comment: @Clayton: Yes, I also realized that and added the edit.

Answer (score 1):

The $1$ is redundant. We know that $M$ cannot equal zero as $-m'<a(n)<M'$ are strict inequalities.

Writing $M=\{|m'|, |m''|, |M'|, |M''|, |L_1|, |L_2|\}$ would be sufficient for the proof.